# Can we upgrade android version of any device?

Tags: updates, 4.3-jelly-bean

I have a Sony Xperia M device with Android 4.3 the official support for the device was stopped in 2015-16. Now is that possible to update the android version to 5 or 6?

If yes, how? I tried many sites but it is very tricky to understand for a beginner like me.

My main question is will the Android 5 app work on my device after upgrading?

**EDIT: I will be great if you reopen the question I have something to share with people who came across this same issue or question in future.**

Comment: "I tried many sites but it is very tricky to understand for a beginner like me." - you *have to* try and understand, or accept it and get stuck. // "reopen the question ... same issue or question in future" - and those will be marked as dupe and point to those wiki posts as well, it's how Android.SE works and avoids clutter.

Comment: Finally I managed to upgrade my android system from jelly bean to nougat and I wanted to share my experience so that if some one in future stuck with same question can resolve it!